# Does boost::optional trigger a ref count on shared_ptr?

Tags: c++, boost, shared-ptr

I'm trying to get a function to return an optional value from my map. So something like this:

```
boost::optional<V> findValue(const K& key) {
    boost::optional<V> ret;
    auto it = map.find(key);
    if (it != map.end()) {
        ret = it->second;
    }
    return ret;
}
```

If `V` happens to be a `shared_ptr` type of some kind, does the assignment to `ret` trigger a reference count?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it has to. `boost::optional` stores a copy, so for a `shared_ptr`, this means there is a copy of the `shared_ptr` and that means the reference count must be increased.

Note that as long as the `boost::optional` is empty, i.e., it doesn't contain a value of `shared_ptr`, there is no object whose reference count is fiddled with. In other words, an empty `boost::optional` does *not* contain an (empty or otherwise) `shared_ptr`.

The requested "semantics" can't really work because you keep one `shared_ptr` in the map and you return a `shared_ptr`.

However, you may return a `boost::optional<const V&>`:

```
boost::optional<const V&> findValue(const K& key) {
    auto it = map.find(key);
    if (it != map.end()) {
        return boost::optional<const V&>( it->second );
    }
    return boost::optional<const V&>();
}
```

but make sure that the reference remains valid while you keep/use it.

Comment: @Barry That would seriously violate the `shared_ptr` invariants, wouldn't it?

Comment: Is it possible to create `boost::optional<std::reference_wrapper<const std::shared_ptr<T>>>`?

Comment: @Barry Turns out you can use a reference with `boost::optional`, that might provide a way to get rid of the reference count problem.

Comment: Personally, I'd return a pointer rather than an optional reference.

Comment: I agree with M. Seymour - I consider the real difference between a reference and a pointer as the idea of the pointer being optional (possibly null).

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Copying a shared pointer, in this case by copy-initialising the one contained in the `optional` object, will increment the use count.